# Change in kinetic energy of mass pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, string

Imagine a pulley (with non-negligible mass) with two masses hanging from the pulley on a rope on opposite sides. One mass is accelerating downward and the other mass is accelerating upward. We assume that the rope does not slip relative to the pulley during the motion. In this case, the tension force on each mass cannot be equal as there must be non zero torque on the pulley in order for the pulley to rotate. This means that tension does work, but I was told that mechanical energy is conserved in this case. How is this possible?

Comment: Not sure I see the problem with tension doing work. How does that mean mechanical energy isn't conserved? Yes work is being done on the pulley. It is gaining energy in the form of $I\omega^2/2$ (moment of inertia times angular velocity squared). That energy is being lost from the falling blocks' gravitational potential and transferred to the pulley through the rope. All good as far as I can tell.